# How to repeat the input until a special condition is met in Python?

Tags: python, user-input, try-except

I need to take integer inputs from the user and add them to a set. The number of integers is unknown. The input process will end when the user input is "Done".

Here is my code:

```
s = set()
print('Please type the number, when you are done please type "Done":')
while True:
    try:
        a = int(input())
        s.add(a)
    except:
        if a == "Done":
            break
        else:
            print('Integer only, please re-type:')
            continue
print(s)
```

But it didn't work as intended.

My idea is simple. If the user types an integer then it's fine, just add to set `s`. If they type a string (which `int(input()` is wrong), then it will go down to `except`, if the string is "Done", then break the `while True` loop, if it isn't then ask the user to re-type and continue the loop.

Here is the error if I type a string first and if I type normally:

[image: 2 kind of errors]

I tried to use a simple if-else statement at the start but it causes traceback right at `int(input())`.

Comment: `a` isn't a string so it will never equal "Done"

Comment: First save the input in a variable `a = input()` then try to convert it to int and add it to the set `s.add(int(a))`. If that fails, `a` will hold the value of the input and you can compare it to `'DONE'`

Comment: @Jacques Gaudin
Thank you. There is a person below who has an answer the same as your idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the exception happens, `a` remains unset. Try this instead.

```
s = set()
# Notice also correct quoting
print("Please type the number, when you're done please type 'Done':")
while True:
    a = input()
    try:
        n = int(a)
        s.add(n)
    # Avoid blanket except
    except ValueError:
        if a == "Done":
            break
        else:
            print('Integer only, please re-type:')
            continue
print(s)
```

Comment: I think we can still remove if else in the except block and only keep the exception message

Answer (score 10):

Use the two-argument form of `iter` to read the input until `Done` is entered. You can iterate over the resulting iterator, handling integer conversions and updating the set in the body of a `for` loop.

```
s = set()
def get_input():
    return input('''Please type the number, when you're done please type "Done": ''')

for x in iter(get_input, "Done"):
    # x is guaranteed to *not* be Done here, or the loop
    # would have already exited.
    try:
        a = int(x)
    except ValueError:
        print("Integer only, please re-type")
        continue
    s.add(a)
```

If you weren't concerned about error handling, you could reduce this to a single set comprehension:

```
s = {int(x) for x in iter(get_input, "Done")}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I haven't learned the iter method yet. I'm doing some research on google on the iter method right now. Seem like a useful method.

Comment: It's very simple: call the first argument, yielding its return value, until it returns the second argument. The nice thing is that it separates the logic of deciding when to stop iterating from the logic of what to do while it *is* still iterating.

Answer (score 3):

Take the input as a string first and then convert it to integer before adding to the set. This way you can check if the value entered by the user is "Done" and exit the loop if it is.

Something like the code below. Please also check some syntax errors that you have in your code.

```
s = {}
print('Please type the number, when you\'re done please type "Done":')
while True:
    a = input()
    if a == 'Done':
        break
    else:
        try:
            s.add(int(a))
        except:
            print('Integer only, please re-type:')
print(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the code below.

```
s = set()
print('Please type the number, when you\'re done please type "Done":')
while True:
    try:
        a = input()
        if a == "Done":
            break
        s.add(int(a))
    except:
        if a == "Done":
            break
        else:
            print('Integer only, please re-type:')
            continue
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
s = set()
b = True

print("Please type the number, when you're done please type 'Done'.")

while b:
    try:
        a = input("Input: ")
        if a == "Done":
            b = False
            break
        a = int(a)
        s.add(a)
    except ValueError:
        print("Whoops, please type an integer!")
print(s)
```