# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'quit'

Tags: python, user-input

I keep getting this errror message:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Here is my code snippet

```
age = {} 
while age != 'quit': 
      age = input('what is your age?') 
      age = int(age) 
      if age >= 18: 
        print("You're old enough to vote.") 
      else: 
        print("You're not old enough to vote.")
```

Please use **Google Colab **if possible.

I tried the `except ValueError method but it did not work. Maybe I just used it incorrectly:

Comment: Move the quit check before th integer conversion.

Comment: you read from `input` after you check `age != quit` and then convert `age` to `int` you should be doing it in the order read, check, convert.

Comment: You are making mistake of type casting `quit` to integer.
i.e. when user input is `quit` next step does int(`quit`) which will throw the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to repeat the input until a special condition is meet in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71115542/how-to-repeat-the-input-until-a-special-condition-is-meet-in-python)

Comment: FYI "*Please use Google Colab if possible.*" There is nothing special about a solution written in Google Colab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the approach (may not be optimal) is to break the loop once you encounter `ValueError`. Logic can be similar to this

```
while age != 'quit':
    age = input()
    try:
        age = int(age)
        if age >= 18:
            print("You're old enough to vote.")
        else:
            print("You're not old enough to vote.")
    except ValueError:
        break
```